# Linked list, if element in param in __init__() is iterable, construct new linked llist from it

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, linked-list, initialization

I have this implementation of linked list,

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class Linked_list:
    def __init__(self, llist=None):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        if llist is not None:
            for i in llist:
                self.append(i)

    def add_head(self, data):
        self.head = Node(data, self.head)
        if self.tail is None:
            self.tail = self.head

    def append(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.add_head(data)
        else:
            self.tail.next = Node(data)
            self.tail = self.tail.next
```

I want to change the `__init__()` so if the `llist` parameter contains an iterable element (list, range(), string, tuple, etc.) it will construct a new Linked_list from it. I'm believe recursion is the way to go, but I'm really confused how to implement it inside the `__init__()`. For example

```
a = Linked_list([1, 2, Linked_list(range(5)), Linked_list(range(3))])
b = Linked_list([1, 2, list(range(5)), list(range(3))])
c = Linked_list([1, 2,  (0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 2)])
```

a,b,c should return same Linked_list

Comment: How deep is the *nesting* you want to account for?  One level or an arbitrary depth?

Comment: Have you treid anything? If so, where are you stuck? Also, your `Linked_list` is not an iterable, to the frist of your examples is not going to work either way.

Comment: @wwii arbitrary depth

Comment: Given your examples do you want each ```Node``` to contain a single integer?

Comment: no, it can be any object or char, even list (added later via append, not in through init)

Comment: So - when you create a ```Linked_list``` any iterable passed to the ```llist``` argument will become another ```Linked_list``` like @FMc's solution?  For *example* ```c```, the third *item* in the ```Linked_list``` will be a ```Node``` with a payload of a ```Linked_list``` *containing* five ```Nodes```?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `isinstance()` to check the types of the values in `llist` and act accordingly. The recursion basically comes for free, via the constructor.

```
from collections import Iterable   # Using Python 2.7

class Linked_list:

    def __init__(self, llist=None):

        ...      # Same as your code.

        if llist is not None:
            for i in llist:
                if isinstance(i, basestring):
                    ll = Linked_list()
                    for c in i:
                        ll.append(c)
                    self.append(ll)
                elif isinstance(i, Iterable):
                    self.append(Linked_list(i))
                else:
                    self.append(i)

    ...

    def __repr__(self):
        xs = []
        nd = self.head
        while nd is not None:
            xs.append(nd.data)
            nd = nd.next
        return repr(xs)

a = Linked_list([1, 2, Linked_list(range(5)), Linked_list(range(3))])
b = Linked_list([1, 2, list(range(5)), list(range(3))])
c = Linked_list([1, 2,  (0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 2)])
d = Linked_list([1, 2,  (0, 1, range(4), 3, 4), (0, 1, [4,5,'abc'])])

print a
print b
print c
print d
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2]]
[1, 2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2]]
[1, 2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2]]
[1, 2, [0, 1, [0, 1, 2, 3], 3, 4], [0, 1, [4, 5, ['a', 'b', 'c']]]]
```

Comment: @m4tu5 In that case, `isinstance()` is probably the way to go. Edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

To test if something is iterable, you can use the [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable) in the `collection.abc` module:

```
isinstance(llist, collection.abc.Iterable)
```

Note that Python defines a behavior/protocol for [iterable objects](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-iterable), it might not be the aim of your exercise but it could be interesting for you to try to conform to it.